# How do I prevent slow motion videos from being selected or shown in UIImagePickerController?

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller

My server doesn't handle the slow motion video file type, so how can I prevent the user from selecting this videos prior to uploading them so it doesn't create a horrible user experience? Or do I need to find a way to process them into a normal video format - if so, how would i do this?

Comment: You got anything for this yet?

Comment: @genaks no luck so far.